# Can I do an iteration in a SQL statements?

Tags: c#, sql, stored-procedures, db2

I have a stored procedure that helps me update some of the accounts where I pass the ID of the account as a parameter. Is there a way that I could create like an iteration of list of accounts and execute the stored procedure in SQL? Or is there any other better options. I could perform the action one at a time. However, I wanted to make it faster and automate it.

FYI, I need to update these accounts(using stored procedure) for testing because every time my app runs it updates the account and I have to revert it back to what it was for testing.

Update:
I have an object with 20 attributes and I'm updating one of its isSold status to False using stored procedure. When my app runs, it updates the status of those objects to true so for testing in the future, I need to revert it's status back to original using stored procedure.

So say, I had 25 object's isSold status to True. Now, I want to revert it back to False using stored procedure. What I want is to create a list of the objects that were sold and have an iteration of the list of objects and execute the stored procedure.

Comment: You could have the SP accept a parameter with the list of account IDs either as an object/user defined data type, or comma separated list that you parse out in the SP and run on multiple IDs at once.  It depends on what the SP is doing, if you have the code to post it would help.

Comment: Can you include more information about the update logic, possibly by way of sample data?

Comment: Hi, I just updated it.

Comment: Sounds like you want a table valued parameter, or possibly pass some JSON/XML in a param. Post the code of the sproc

Comment: *What I want is to create a list of the objects that were sold and have an iteration of the list of objects* - why does `UPDATE t SET IsSold = 0 WHERE IsSold = 1` not work for this? Avoid thinking in C# style "I need a loop, and I need to do something on every pass of the loop as `i` increases" - SQL doesn't work like that, it works on sets of data. You'll forever be "missing the point" of SQL, if you take an iterative view on it